# Will the ' Restrict access to custom metadata types org permission' toggle be available post Spring '20 release?

Tags: release-notes

Hello I am looking at https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter20/release-notes/rn_forcecom_development_custom_metadata_require_cruc.htm and I am slightly confused. It says that to give metadata access via permission sets and profiles which is fine and makes sense as a best practice but was not sure if the toggle would still be available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The toggle to enforce them will still be available in the Schema Settings. By default they will be turned on, but you can reverse that if you need to. This was verified around minute 14 on the webinar on the bottom of the admin site:

https://admin.salesforce.com/blog/2019/secure-custom-metadata-types-and-custom-settings-in-winter-20